# for loop breaking out for some reason after array comparison

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, and I'm comparing two values, and then setting a json object:

```
var compare = ["hh", "pictures", "videos", "aboutMe", "contactMe", "cat", "location"];
var data = ["pictures", "videos", "aboutMe", "contactMe", "cat", "location"];
    for (var j=0; j<compare.length; j++) {
        if (compare[j] === data[j]) {
            self.MenuItems.menu_item[j].added = "added";
        }else if (compare[j] !== data[j]){
            self.MenuItems.menu_item[j].added = "";
        }
    }
```

for some reason, for all `self.MenuItems.menu_item[j]`, they all equal either "added" or "";...

Comment: What do you expect? If they are equal it's set to `"added"`; if not, to `""`.

Comment: well all values are getting set to either "added" or ""...not just one  "" and 6 "added"

Comment: All the items of `self.MenuItems.menu_item` from `0` to `compare.length - 1` will get their `added` property assigned.

Comment: If the `compare` and `data` variables always have those values then all the added properties you assign to will get the value "".

Comment: Do you want to check whether `data` contains a value of `compare` *somewhere*? Currently you're checking the values in both arrays *at the same index*.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know this condition is not very efficient, here how it should be

```
if (compare[j] === data[j]) {
    self.MenuItems.menu_item[j].added = "added";
}else {
    self.MenuItems.menu_item[j].added = "";
}
```

and the code does what is intended. Unless you had something else in mind.

Comment: Could be another tick better if you'd dereference `self.MenuItems.menu_item`